# Need some little help with an ROS Overview

Tags: gazebo, ros-hydro, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

I am still pretty new to ROS. I already did several indtroduction tutorials and stuff and tried to get an overview. But what I still cant figure out is:

- Where is the link betwenn GAZEBOSim and ROS? I am maybe not far enough in tutorials but I am still wondering either    i do tutorials in ROS or Gazebo not now together.
- I am using Ubuntu 14.04 so trusty thar, so the consequence is I have to use ROS Indigo which is not linkable to the newest GAZEBO distro (3.0 would be the newest and Indigo is just supporting 2.2) am I right there? Is there a way to get this and what would be the advantages.
- Is ROS Indigo already as much supported than Hydro or do you recommend me to go an Ubuntu version down to 13.x to work with hydro (there are also some books which are working with Hydro in which i am intrested in)

Please dont shake you head on this questions as I said i just started and wanted to get an overview .

Best Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186881/need-some-little-help-with-an-ros-overview/) by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 232 on 2014-07-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Debty,

welcome to the ROS community.

Gazebo is the standard robot simulator of ROS. In the past Gazebo was developed as the ROS robot simulator. In the newer versions the development goal changed to "a generic robot simulator that works pretty well with ROS but is also stand alone". This might be the cause why you don't see the link between both at the moment.

Yes Indigo uses the 2.x version of Gazebo. The Gazebo Wiki says:

> ROS Indigo hosts the 2.x version of Gazebo. For a fully-integrated ROS system, we recommend using the 2.x version of Gazebo.

I think it is not impossible to use Gazebo 3.x with Indigo but it might cost some time and headache. For a ROS beginner maybe a little bit more time and something more like a brain tumor than headache.

Your last question has been answered 10 hours ago in [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/186722/should-i-use-hydro-or-indigo-for-my-new-project/).

Regards

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3